# QWebView loading https page via proxy failed

Tags: qt, ssl, https

I have problem loading https page via proxy. problem.
Here is the code used to set the proxy:

```
proxy = QNetworkProxy()
proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.HttpProxy)
proxy.setHostName('127.0.0.1')
proxy.setPort(10001)
QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy(proxy)
```

I'm sure it's not the proxy problem. Http page can be loaded successfully.
And Qt is configured with SSL support. Https page can be loaded without the proxy setting.

How can I load https page via proxy?

Update: I wonder if it is the certificate problem because the proxy is built on GAE, and visit https page with fake certificate. But Qt didn't output any error log on that.

Answer (score 1):

It is solved.
It is the problem of certificate. After I import my certificate into system-wide certificate authority database, the page can be loaded.